# Convert phone number from alphabetic to numeric form

Tags: c, arrays, character

I'm doing an exercise from KNKings book "C Programming: A modern approach" which involves converting a phone number in alphabetic form, entered by the user, into numeric form. When the program encounters non-alphabetic characters (digits or punctuations, for example), it should leave them unchanged. I may assume that the user only enters upper-case letters.

However, my program seems to produce garbage, to say the least.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 50

int main(void)
{
    char alphabetic[MAX_SIZE], ch;
    int num_elements = 0;

    printf("Enter phone number: ");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE && ((ch = getchar()) != '\n'); i++){
        alphabetic[i] = ch;
        num_elements++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= num_elements; i++){
        switch (alphabetic[i]){
            case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': alphabetic[i] = '2'; break;
            case 'D': case 'E': case 'F': alphabetic[i] = '3'; break;
            case 'G': case 'H': case 'I': alphabetic[i] = '4'; break;
            case 'J': case 'K': case 'L': alphabetic[i] = '5'; break;
            case 'M': case 'N': case 'O': alphabetic[i] = '6'; break;
            case 'P': case 'R': case 'S': alphabetic[i] = '7'; break;
            case 'T': case 'U': case 'V': alphabetic[i] = '8'; break;
            case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': alphabetic[i] = '9'; break;
            default:                                           break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", alphabetic);
    return 0;
}
```

In particular, I enter: COLLECT-800. 
It outputs something like this: u░@■   ║k ╩

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `ch` should be `int`.

Comment: @Lundin Could you explain why?

Comment: @Shuster not related to your problem, but you're missing the `Q` and the `Z` case.

Comment: @Shuster Because getchar returns an int and EOF is an int.

Comment: @Shuster ... but as you don't test for `EOF` in your code, you get away with `char`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky If OP's goal is to emulate character keys on a phone, keep in mind that it wasn't until recently that Q and Z were added; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad#Layout

Comment: @Jabberwocky I should have clarified that in the book 'Q' and 'Z' are left out deliberately. I'm sorry.

Comment: @GovindParmar good point, I didn't know that. But I'm not sure your definition of "recent" is accurate, my first cell phone (20 year ago or so) already had the Q and Z ;-)

Comment: @Shuster no problem, this is not actually wrong. But I suppose the book is pretty old.

Comment: the variable: `numElements` is not needed as the variable 'i' already contains the count when the `for()` loop is exited

Comment: after the first `for()` loop, need to terminate the string with: `alphabetic[i] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `char alphabetic[MAX_SIZE];`  This should be: `char alphabetic[MAX_SIZE+1];` to allow for the trailing NUL byte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea, but there are two things missing in your program:

1. Most importantly, the null terminator at the end of the string. After your `for` loop in which you read the number, add the line:

   ```
   alphabetic[i] = '\0';
   ```
2. If the user enters lowercase letters, they are ignored in the `switch` statement. To get around this, include `<ctype.h>` and change the `switch` quantity from `alphabetic[i]` to `toupper(alphabetic[i])`. Calling `toupper` on an already upper case letter is benign.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help, but is there any way to make sure that the null terminator gets added automatically after the program finishes reading characters?

Comment: @Shuster To achieve that you should use a method that is actually intended for reading strings rather than individual characters (i.e. `getchar`) from `stdin`; `fgets` is a good choice.

Answer (score 4):

You're not putting a null-terminator anywhere so it's undefined behavior when you read the string regardless of whether you modified it afterwards. Put this line:

```
alphabetic[num_elements] = 0;
```

After your `for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE &&...` loop.

---

Personally, I wouldn't do the `getchar` loop and instead read in the string like this:

```
scanf("%49s", alphabetic); // reads in a string up to 50 characters
for (i = 0; alphabetic[i]; i++) { ...
```

Comment: this is not quite correct.  The input format specifier 's' always appends a NUL byte to the input, so the statement should be: `scanf("%49s", alphabetic);`